# Unable to set OLEObjects properties when the worksheet is not active or the window is minimized

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to initialize an Excel worksheet by setting properties of some OLE Objects in the worksheet with the code below placed in a standard module.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UserView")
    .btnShowAllItems.Enabled = False
    .btnShowAllItems.Visible = False
    .btnAvailableOnly.Enabled = True
    .btnAvailableOnly.Visible = True
    .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End With
```

The above code works as intended except when the sub is called while Excel window is minimized or the user is in a different worksheet, resulting in the error below.

```
Run-time error '1004':
Unable to set the Enabled property of the OLEObject class
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I set the properties while the Excel window is minimized or  when the user is in a different worksheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `.Object` when calling `Enabled` - that fixed it for me

```vb
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UserView")
    .btnShowAllItems.Object.Enabled = False
    .btnShowAllItems.Visible = False
    .btnAvailableOnly.Object.Enabled = True
    .btnAvailableOnly.Visible = True
    .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End With
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you Tim!  If you know why .Object is required for this I'm all ears sir

Comment: Sorry to disappoint but I don't really have a good idea why - just tried adding `Object` and it worked...